# How to combine/overwrite 2 columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two column in my dataframe. I want to combine/overwrite the columns.

Two Columns:

```
Column1 Column2
0   NaT NaT
1   2019-07-17 11:33:22 NaT
2   NaT NaT
3   NaT 2018-05-24 10:00:48
```

Desired Result:

```
NewColumn
0   NaT
1   2019-07-17 11:33:22
2   NaT
3   2018-05-24 10:00:48
```

NaT type:

```
type(df['Column1'][0])
```

Output:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType
```

Date type:

```
type(df['Column1'][1])
```

Output:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

**`fillna()`**

```
final=df.assign(New_Col=df.Column1.fillna(df.Column2))
```

Or:

**`ffill()`** and **`iloc[]`**

```
final=df.assign(New_Col=df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1])
```

---

```
              Column1              Column2             New_Col
0                 NaT                  NaT                 NaT
1 2019-07-17 11:33:22                  NaT 2019-07-17 11:33:22
2                 NaT                  NaT                 NaT
3                 NaT  2018-05-24 10:00:48 2018-05-24 10:00:48
```

*Code to reproduce the* df:

```
d=[{'Column1': pd.NaT, 'Column2': 'NaT'},
   {'Column1': pd.Timestamp('2019-07-17 11:33:22'), 'Column2': 'NaT'},
   {'Column1': pd.NaT, 'Column2': pd.NaT},
   {'Column1': pd.NaT, 'Column2': pd.Timestamp('2018-05-24 10:00:48')}]
pd.DataFrame(d)
```